# GetLegendGraphic from layergroup in Geoserver 2.8.2

Tags: geoserver, sld, group-layer, getlegendgraphic

I am working with Geoserver 2.8.2

I am requesting a GetLegendGraphic to a layer group that holds three layers, each layer with one single SLD styling.

I am getting a legend from Geoserver, but not as desired. The legend is showing the name of the layers in the layergroup and i do not want to show the layer names, i just want to show the labels (forceLables:on), but not the layer names!

Is there any way to do that? Any vendor parameter that can handle it?